# how to relate two point in a sublots with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am importing from an excel file called ('BW1_StartValues') 3 columns of values (C,h,L*) that represents coordinates defining colour numerically. Each row of L, C, h define a specific colour.

I would like to create a interactive scatter subplot with 2 figures, one where I plot C and h and one where I plot L along a vertical line. I want to be able to relate each point in the 2 figures, for example, when I would click on one point in the 1st figure, I would see its related values in the 2nd figure.

I found on stackoverflow a piece of code similar to what I want, but I am having problem when I import data from a file and then try to use the code. I am relatively new in Python, and can't find where my code is mistaken.

Thank you for your help !
Gauthier

```
def main():

    fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(15,8))
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2, width_ratios=[8, 1]) 

    df1 = read_excel('BW1_StartValues.xlsx')
    C = df1['C']
    h = df1['h']
    L = df1['L*']  

    x1 = np.ones((14,1))

    for (ax1,ax2), marker in zip((ax1,ax2), ['o', 'o']):
        x = C
        y = h
        x,y = x,y

    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])

    ax1.plot(h,C, ls='',marker = marker, label = 'BW1 samples' )
    ax1.plot(h_mean, C_mean, ls='',marker = marker, color='red', label = 'mean value')

    ax1.set_xlabel('h', fontsize = 14)
    ax1.set_ylabel('C*', fontsize = 14)
    ax1.legend(loc='lower right', fontsize = 15)
    ax1.set_xlim(255,280)
    ax1.set_ylim(25,50)

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1])

    axe2.set_ylabel('L*', fontsize = 14)

    ax2.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
    ax2.set_xlim(0.8,1.2,1)
    ax2.tick_params(labelleft='off',labelright='on')
    ax2.yaxis.set_label_position('right')

    plt.suptitle('BW1 samples', y = 0.95)



    ax2.plot(x1, L, ls='', marker=marker)
    ax2.plot(1, L_mean, ls='', marker=marker, color='red')

    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05, top =0.95)


    IndexedHighlight((ax1,ax2))
    plt.show()

class IndexedHighlight(HighlightingDataCursor):
    def __init__(self, axes, **kwargs):
        # Use the first plotted Line2D in each axes
        artists = [ax.lines[0] for ax in axes]

        kwargs['display'] = 'single'
        HighlightingDataCursor.__init__(self, artists, **kwargs)
        self.highlights = [self.create_highlight(artist) for artist in artists]
        plt.setp(self.highlights, visible=False)

    def update(self, event, annotation):
        # Hide all other annotations
        plt.setp(self.highlights, visible=False)

        # Highlight everything with the same index.
        artist, ind = event.artist, event.ind
        for original, highlight in zip(self.artists, self.highlights):
            h, C = original.get_data()
            highlight.set(visible=True, xdata=h[ind], ydata=C[ind])
        DataCursor.update(self, event, annotation)

main()
```

Comment: I think you will understand that it's hard to help you without a clear problem description (what is the problem? what do you get, what would you like to see instead?) and a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: Sorry not be clear enough ! And thanks for the minimal, complete and verifiable, that will allow me to rephrase my problem in better terms.